# How can methods in an object's prototype access property values of said object?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I created this function that is supposed to create/return an object with a custom prototype and basic properties. The issue is that when I try to call the methods from the object's prototype, I get the error: is not a function. My guess is that maybe it has to do with the `this` keyword, but I'm not sure. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```js
const bookProto = {
  getPrice() {
    return this.price;
  },
  getInfo() {
    return `${this.title} by ${this.author}`;
  },
  addRating(str) {
    this.rating = str;
  },
  getRating() {
    return this.rating.length;
  },
};

function createBook(id, title, author, price) {
  let book = Object.create(bookProto);
  book = {
    id,
    title,
    author,
    price,
    rating: [],
  };
  return book;
}
```

Comment: You create an instance of the object using the prototype and `Object.create`, then immediate throw it away by setting the same variable to an object literal. You'll have to set the fields individually, or add a function that sets the properties from an object literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning a new object to `book` **replaces** the existing value. It doesn't merge with the object you have there.

You need to assign the new property values one by one.

```
function createBook(id, title, author, price) {
  const book = Object.create(bookProto);
  book.id = id;
  book.title = title;
  book.author = author;
  book.price = price;
  return book;
}
```